# SQL - group by into column updating

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I'm playing with `AdvantureWorks` DB, but I don't have Actual Sales values on `SalesOrderDetail` table. This line supposed to contain `LineTotal` aggregation by order id.

I need to enter those values into Actual Sales column to each order ID line:

```
select SUM(LineTotal) as ActualSales
from Sales.SalesOrderDetail
group by SalesOrderID
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the field you want to group by to the query:

```
select SalesOrderID, sum(LineTotal) as ActualSales 
from SalesOrderDetail 
group by SalesOrderID
```

Comment: craigmj,

this statement presents ActualSales as an alias, but does not update the values on ActualSales column.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can `UPDATE` with `JOIN` like so:

```
UPDATE od
SET od.ActualSalesColumn = g.ActualSales
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail od
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
      SalesOrderDetail, 
      SUM(LineTotal) as ActualSales 
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail 
    GROUP BY SalesOrderID
) g ON od.SalesOrderID = g.SalesOrderID;
```

**Or:** With a CTE:

```
WITH ActualSales
AS
(
     SELECT 
       SalesOrderDetail, 
       SUM(LineTotal) as ActualSales 
     FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail 
     GROUP BY SalesOrderID
)
UPDATE od
SET od.ActualSalesColumn = g.ActualSales
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail od
INNER JOIN ActualSales g ON od.SalesOrderID = g.SalesOrderID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE x
SET x.ActualSales = x.NewActualSales
FROM (
      SELECT ActualSales, SUM(LineTotal) OVER (PARTITION BY SalesOrderID) AS NewActualSales
      FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
      ) x
```